# Ajax call working on Google Chrome but not on IE 11

Tags: java, ajax, rest, google-chrome, internet-explorer-11

I am developing a `RESTFul web service` project which has a `POJO` as below:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Input {
    //variable declarations 

   public Input(){
      //default constructor 
   }

   //constructor no 1
   public Input(String LR, double ECH,double CSH,String APP) {
        this.LR = LR;
        this.ECH = ECH;
        this.CSH = CSH;
        this.APP = APP;
    }

    //constructor no 2
    public Input(String LR, double ECH,double CSH,String APP,...) {
        this.LR = LR;
        this.ECH = ECH;
        this.CSH = CSH;
        this.APP = APP;
        //constructor of all other parameters including these
    }

//getters and setters method below.
}
```

My ajax is getting called on this button:

```
<button type="submit" onClick='functionname();' class="btn btn-primary" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span>Function</button>
```

The `Controller` class I have is as follows:

```
@Path("/input")
public class InputResponse {
InputService inputservice = new InputService();

@PUT
@Path("/approve")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void approveInputRecord(Input obj) throws Exception{
    String LR = obj.getLR();
    double CSH = obj.getCSH();
    double ECH = obj.getECH();
    String APP = obj.getAPP();
    Input input = new Input(LR,CSH,ECH,APP);
    input = inputservice.approveTransaction(input);
    }
}
```

The `Service` Class for the same is as below:

```
public class InputService {

CallableStatement stmt;
Statement commitStmt;

public InputService(){
    //database connection
}

public Input approveTransaction(Input input) throws SQLException {
    commitStmt = dcc.con.createStatement();
    stmt=dcc.con.prepareCall("BEGIN APPROVRTRANSACTION(?,?,?,?); END;");
    stmt.setString(1, input.getLR());
    stmt.setDouble(2, input.getECH());
    stmt.setDouble(3, input.getCSH());
    stmt.setString(4, input.getAPP());
    stmt.execute();
    commitStmt.executeQuery("COMMIT");
    return input;
}
}
```

Inside my `JAVA Script` my `ajax` call to above is:

```
    var obj = {
    LogReference : logreference,
    EuroclearHoldings:euroclearholdings,
    ClearstreamHoldings:clearstreamholdings,
    Approver : loginXPID
}
var jsonobj = JSON.stringify(obj);
$.ajax({
    url:'./webapi/input/approve',
    type: 'PUT',
    data:jsonobj,
    cache:false,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(data)
    {
        alert('success');
    },
    error:function(xhr,textstatus,errorthrown){
        alert(xhr.responseText);
        alert(textstatus);
        alert(errorthrown);
    }
},'json');
```

Having this as my code my application is working fine on `Google Chrome` but sometimes works and sometimes not on `Internet Explorer 11`. This is the strange behavior. And the other thing which I am unable to get is even if it works on `Chrome` the `ajax` call always getting the `alerts` in error. Can anybody please explain why is it so? And how do I solve it? Any help much appreciated.
**Update**

Here is the output on `network --> Response` tab on chrome when error is thrown. But despite that I still get the output.
[image]

Many Thanks

Comment: You can try using `POST` requests instead of `PUT`.

Comment: @MadushanPerera If I use `POST` or `PUT` it is giving the same issue. But for `GET` it is not working on either of the browsers and giving error `no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'`

Comment: could you please provide server responce from 'Network' tab of the Chrome browser.

Comment: @MeetJoeBlack Please check my edit and let me know what all you think.

Comment: sory, but you may only provide a screen with 'approve xhr' call form 'Network' tab(its in red color now), so you must click on it  and make a screen of 'Responce' tab. pls replace your huge screens.

Comment: nothing is showing up in the same. It is red right now because I have an alert that is blocking it from going. While the alert stays, I cannot click on the error and provide you with the response tab. The moment I click ok on the alert, it moves out and the error does too. after that everything is ok with 200 response and no errors. @MeetJoeBlack

Comment: what should I do? @MeetJoeBlack

Comment: Please check my edit. The values that I am supposed to be getting are being received. But I also find the `ResponseType = ""` to be a bit unusual. Any ideas on what the ResponseType should be as well? @MeetJoeBlack

Comment: at first remove ,'json' from .ajax second parameter;

Comment: @MeetJoeBlack The picture I have added earlier is the same picture which I have got after debugging my application on server. Let me know if any other thing needed.

Comment: @peeskillet can you please suggest anything upon it.

Comment: @MeetJoeBlack hey any update?

Comment: It's also works fine when I run the application in debug mode on internet explorer.

Comment: @tpsaitwal, I would suggest that we should gather more information, by using consolelog instead of alert in your error callback and edit your question by adding the error messages you get. Those might give us more clues. Also, you could tell us what have you received as a response from the server.

Comment: @LajosArpad it's giving the error message as `Bad Request`.

Comment: I see. If the path of /input/approve valid? If you look at your routes, do you see any problems regarding it?

Comment: Is PUT intentional? Does the server handle the put request to that path? Is the server receiving the request? Do you have errors on server-side?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96885/discussion-between-lajos-arpad-and-tpsaitwal).

Comment: As a warning, please do not use comments on unrelated questions and answers to ask others to answer your question. These comments have all been removed.

Comment: Could you please validate your javascript. You can use this tool and check http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: why there is dot in the url ? "./webapi/input/approve" . do not use alert() ,use concole.log() instead. @tpsaitwal please check the dot in the url.

Comment: @TheNeoNoirDeveloper this is in my `web.xml` for `RESTful web service`. And that was not my issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I can see your `Button type="submit"`. If it is inside the `form tag` then call the `ajax request` in `action` of the file. As I can see from above comments this might be the issue. As you are submitting something this changes to a `POST` request and not `GET` request so its giving the error method not allowed. And looking at the solution just change the `Button type='button'` or call the `ajax` on the `action` of `form tag`. It should work.